# Error when trying to insert input from user into SQL table

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I'm having a problem, whenever I try to run the code below and select the statement 2 to **insert a tool** and put a random tool name I get the error message : **ProgrammingError('column "inserttool' does not exist\nLine 1: insert tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(@insertTool, '2')** .

Here is the code :

```
if Menu == "2":
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  InsertTool = raw_input("Please insert the tool that you want to add.\n")
  insert_tool = """insert into tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(@InsertTool, '2')"""  
  try:
     cursor.execute( insert_tool);
     connection.commit();
     print("Tool is succesfully inserted!")

  except Exception as e:
     connection.rollback();
     print("Exception Occured : ",e)
  connection.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
if Menu == "2":
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  InsertTool = raw_input("Please insert the tool that you want to add.\n")
  insert_tool = """insert into tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(%s, %s)"""
  val = (InsertTool, "2")
  try:
     cursor.execute(insert_tool, val);
     connection.commit();
     print("Tool is succesfully inserted!")

  except Exception as e:
     connection.rollback();
     print("Exception Occured : ",e)
  connection.close();
```

Comment: thank you very much, now it works perfectly! I appreciate the help! :)